# Does "aimed application" mean something specific?

Tags: education

I was reading about an uninstall tool that was especially useful for removing "aimed applications."  When I tried to find out what that meant (beyond the obvious, "targeted at a specific group") I found it *used* quite a bit, but I have been unable to find an actual definition of the term.  Since I'm asking here, I'm obviously interested in the term as used for the programs the uninstall tool can target and not the term from the medical, advertising or any other domains.

If there's a better place to ask about a computer term, please direct me there and accept my apologies for wasting your time.

EDIT:  Here are a few links to pages that use the term without defining it (at least not in any way I recognize as "defining"):

https://techdows.com/2010/08/uses-of-hunter-mode-in-revo-uninstaller.html

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7367021

https://books.google.com/books?id=vdCeBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=what+is+an+%22aimed+application%22&source=bl&ots=CYk_PlUnF5&sig=ACfU3U0wLGAjj7P5wFC09Sun310ap3rA5A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid9rO9x-vjAhXsYt8KHdNkChg4ChDoATAAegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20an%20%22aimed%20application%22&f=false

https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/how-to-activate-the-aimed-application-when-displaying-a-cocoa-alert/185

Comment: Might be a marketing term.

Comment: Perhaps you could give appropriate links?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: some example links have been added.  The first one is the article I was reading.

Comment: I don't think this is a computer science question. Perhaps [su]?

Comment: It seems "aimed application" doesn't have a technical meaning after all. It is just an application that you're applying the uninstaller on. See "Hunter Mode offers one-click uninstall, stop or delete by aiming applications on the desktop, Quick launch bar, system tray or opened applications."

Comment: Yup.  It seems it was just a odd choice of words (IMHO) to use for the application you want to select.  I guess the way it was used, plus finding it on many other sites in other software contexts caused me to think a new term for a special class of applications had come into use.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.  Thanks for the help!